# How to fill row ongridview

Tags: asp.net

work on ASP.net C# vs05.Gridview have several rows,Each row have three column.I want to fill those column by Table values.

I dont want to use :
Gridview.datasource=TableValues;
Gridview.Databind();

I want to fill each row columns separately.How to ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547392/how-to-add-row-on-gridview (please don't post the same question multiple times)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can manipulate data after databinding by simply using RowBound event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx